# In an Inertial Measurement Unit, how are the body-axis velocities calculated?

Tags: airspeed, inertial-nav-system

What are body-axis velocity components (u,v,w)? Are they calculated from IMU acceleration components (Ax,Ay,Az)?

How can this be related with the airspeed measured from the pitot tube?

Comment: Relative to which frame of reference are the body-axis velocity components?

Comment: I was going to flag the question as it's easily googlable.  But I noticed two questions. The relation to airspeed is interesting.  I look forward to seeing the answer.

Comment: @mins, I doubt IMU can compute airspeed via wind vector as the only way to compute the wind vector is comparing the ground velocity, from IMU + GPS, with the true air velocity, from air data.

Comment: The body-axis velocity components can only be related in magnitude to the airspeed. That is unless you know angle of attack and sideslip angle from some other sensors. Then you have three equations and three unknowns for the wind velocity. The vector equation is airspeed velocity = body axis velocity - wind velocity.

Comment: @mins, that does not allow calculating the head/tailwind component and since the cross-track angle is affected by that too, not really the crosswind component either.

Comment: @mins, I believe yes. And altitude and temperature, because you need _true_ airspeed.

Comment: @Jan Hudec: were you referring to my post? Please clarify.

Comment: @jjack, no, I was not as should be obvious from the fact that I @-mentioned mins.